# What is needed to be done in an SQLite DatabaseErrorHandler

Tags: android, sqlite, error-handling, database-restore

I've been working on refining a working **SQLite** database restore. More specifically, at when the database is corrupted (I've been using a file with SQL in it and copying this to the database file instead of a copy of the database).

I can handle this without a handler by using SQL to look at **sqlite_master**, (no tables detects the corruption).

As I came across DatabaseErrorHanlder while researching techniques, I thought that I would dabble with the **DatabaseErorHandler**.

I've got to the stage of triggering the DataBaseErrorHandler (log within the handler gets called (twice due to 2nd attempt to read)). However I then get more errors reported than if I use null instead of the handler and the app crashes (as if having the handler turns off SQLite's automated, I believe, deletion of the corrupt file, and hence any invocation of the handler recreating it). The crash isn't an issue as such clearly SQLite has tried to get around the corruption, but it appears that the handler stops it doing what it otherwise does.)

Running without the handler results in the following messages (first is written by the App as a roadmark):-

```
11-03 16:36:13.414 10959-10959/? I/mjt.shopper: Thu Nov 03 16:36:13 AEDT 2016 Activity=dataBaseIntegrityCheck Method=MainDataHandling MSG=restore Database Integrity Check - IC Database created
11-03 16:36:13.415 10959-10959/? E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
11-03 16:36:13.416 10959-10959/? E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/mjt.shopper/databases/ICShopper
11-03 16:36:13.416 10959-10959/? E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: deleting the database file: /data/data/mjt.shopper/databases/ICShopper
```

Running with the handler I get (same roadmark + roadmark issued by the handler) :-

```
11-03 16:58:23.923 12265-12265/? I/mjt.shopper: Thu Nov 03 16:58:23 AEDT 2016 Activity=dataBaseIntegrityCheck Method=MainDataHandling MSG=restore Database Integrity Check - IC Database created
11-03 16:58:23.925 12265-12265/? E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
11-03 16:58:23.925 12265-12265/? I/mjt.shopper: Thu Nov 03 16:58:23 AEDT 2016 Activity=MainDataHandling Method=dataBaseIntegrityCheck MSG=DB onCorruption error handler invoked
11-03 16:58:23.925 12265-12265/? E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
11-03 16:58:23.927 12265-12265/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/mjt.shopper/databases/ICShopper'.
                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
.............
11-03 16:58:23.928 12265-12265/? E/SQLiteOpenHelper: Couldn't open ICShopper for writing (will try read-only):
                                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
'''''''''''''
11-03 16:58:23.929 12265-12265/? E/SQLiteLog: (26) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA user_version;] file is encrypted or is not a database
11-03 16:58:23.930 12265-12265/? I/mjt.shopper: Thu Nov 03 16:58:23 AEDT 2016 Activity=MainDataHandling Method=dataBaseIntegrityCheck MSG=DB onCorruption error handler invoked
11-03 16:58:23.934 12265-12265/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-03 16:58:23.934 12265-12265/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: mjt.shopper, PID: 12265
                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26)
```

The DatabaseHelper code is :-

```
public class IntegrityCheckDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DatabaseErrorHandler{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "IC"+ShopperDBHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
    public static final int DATABASE_CORRUPTED = 1;
    private static int databasestate = 0;
    private Context context;

    public IntegrityCheckDBHelper(Context context,
                                  String name,
                                  SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                                  int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,factory,1,errorHandler);
        this.context = context;

    };

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {};
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {};
    public void onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    public boolean checkDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase icdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String icsqlstr = " PRAGMA quick_check";
        Cursor iccsr;
        iccsr = icdb.rawQuery(icsqlstr,null);
        return false;
    }
    public static void setDatabaseCorrupted() {
        databasestate = DATABASE_CORRUPTED;
    }
    public boolean isDatabaseCouurpted() {
        if(databasestate != 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note! this Helper is specifically for checking that a restore file can be user (so no need for `onCreate`/`onUpgrade` to do anything **I think**).

Here's the relevant code i.e. the **dataBaseIntegrityCheck** method (*i.e create a database file from the backup being restored from to check if the backup creates a valid database*):-

```
private boolean dataBaseIntegrityCheck() {

        final String THIS_METHOD = "dataBaseIntegrityCheck";
        String sqlstr_mstr = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name!='android_metadata' ORDER by name;";
        Cursor iccsr;
        boolean rv = true;
        DatabaseErrorHandler myerrorhandler = new DatabaseErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
                mjtUtils.logMsg(mjtUtils.LOG_INFORMATIONMSG,"DB onCorruption error handler invoked",THIS_ACTIVITY,THIS_METHOD,true);
                dbcorrupted = true;
            }
        };
        mjtUtils.logMsg(mjtUtils.LOG_INFORMATIONMSG,"Restore Databae Integrity Check - Starting",THIS_METHOD,THIS_ACTIVITY,true);
        try {
            FileInputStream bkp = new FileInputStream(backupfilename);
            OutputStream ic = new FileOutputStream(icdbfilename);
            while ((copylength = bkp.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                ic.write(buffer, 0, copylength);
            }
            ic.close();
            bkp.close();

            mjtUtils.logMsg(mjtUtils.LOG_INFORMATIONMSG,"restore Database Integrity Check - IC Database created",THIS_METHOD,THIS_ACTIVITY,true);

            //Note SQLite will actually check for corruption and if so delete the file
            IntegrityCheckDBHelper icdbh = new IntegrityCheckDBHelper(this,null,null,1,myerrorhandler);

            //>>>>>>>>>>>>> Errors all point here (the getReadableDatabase)
            SQLiteDatabase icdb = icdbh.getReadableDatabase();

            if(dbcorrupted) {
                mjtUtils.logMsg(mjtUtils.LOG_INFORMATIONMSG,"DB corrupted",THIS_ACTIVITY,THIS_METHOD,true);
                return false;
            }

            //Check to see if there are any tables, if wrong file type shouldn't be any
            iccsr = icdb.rawQuery(sqlstr_mstr,null);
            if(iccsr.getCount() < 1) {
                errlist.add("Integrity Check extract from sqlite_master returned nothing - Propsoed file is corrupt or not a database file.");
                rv = false;
            }
            iccsr.close();
            icdb.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errlist.add("Integrity Check Failed Error Message was " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(!rv) {
            // AlertDialog removed.
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

**To re-iterate, the question is mostly in regard to the DatabaseErrorHandler and what I can, can't and/or should be doing.**

The documentation, that I found and also many posts that I've looked at don't appear to that helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code in `SQLiteDatabase.open()` looks like this:

```java
        try {
            openInner();
        } catch (SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException ex) {
            onCorruption();
            openInner();
        }
```

So your `onCorruption()` handler must restore the database before it returns; this cannot be delayed until later.

If you do not actually want to restore the database you're trying to open, using the `onCorrupt()` handler does not make sense.

Comment: In my case. I don't need the database as point proven wrong type of file being used for restore. try again (the real database is still sitting there nice and happy). However, I will try what you've suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I have been unable to understand what you're trying to say with this comment.

Comment: I'm creating a database solely to check if the file (should be a copy of a database file) is actually a copy of the live database. If it isn't a copy of a database (i.e. it is corrupt) then it can't be used to restore the real database. if it isn't then the user will be told it's not a valid file and the real database is used without it being changed. Hope that explains it better.